# Why can't I produce a Numpy Array from my list? Indexing Error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

Trying to follow the Scipy [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#linear-sum-assignment-problem-example) to apply the linear_sum_assignment function to my code, in which I'm trying to assign 1 robot to each pizza so that the total travel time of the robots is as small as possible.

Robots is a list of 6 robot objects of which I am purposely ignoring the first robot.
SwapTargets is a list of 5 Pizza objects

```
newlist = []
for j in range(1,len(Robots)):
  for i in range(0,len(SwapTargets)):
    ref_x = SwapTargets[i].coordinates[0]
    ref_y = SwapTargets[i].coordinates[1]
    value = ((ref_x - Robots[j].x)**2) + (ref_y - Robots[j].y)**2
    newlist.append(value)
  
myarray = np.array(newlist).reshape(len(Robots[1:]),len(SwapTargets))  

from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

row_ind, col_ind = linear_sum_assignment(myarray)

PizzaList = np.array([SwapTargets])[row_ind]
RobotList = np.array([Robots[1:]])[col_ind]
result = dict(zip(PizzaList, RobotList))
print(result)
```

At `PizzaList = np.array([SwapTargets])[row_ind]`
I'm getting an error `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1`

Just as a test, If I replace `[SwapTargets]` with `["A,"B","C","D","E"]` in `PizzaList = np.array([SwapTargets])[row_ind]` in I pull no error, but dont understand why my list of 5 objects does not work.

Thx from a python noobie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost answering your own question. You state that *SwapTargets is a list of 5 Pizza objects*. This means that it could have been initialized like this:

```py
SwapTargets = [pizza0, pizza1, pizza2, pizza3, pizza4, pizza5]
```

Then you say that while executing:

```
PizzaList = np.array(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])[row_ind]
```

works, executing

```
PizzaList = np.array([SwapTargets])[row_ind]
```

does not. To understand what's going on, simply substitute the initialization of `SwapTargets` for the identifier, the above becomes:

```
PizzaList = np.array([[pizza0, pizza1, pizza2, pizza3, pizza4, pizza5]])[row_ind]
```

See the double nested brackets?

What's happening here is that you are calling `np.array()` on a list of just one item (that item itself is a list of 5 items). In the successful call, you were calling the same function of a list of 5 items, which is probably what you want.

What you wanted to write was actually:

```
PizzaList = np.array(SwapTargets)[row_ind]
```

(no brackets around the argument).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the difference between the following:

```
>>> numpy.array([1,2,3])
array([1, 2, 3])
```

and

```
>>> numpy.array([[1,2,3]])
array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

The first is a vector of length `3`, the second is a matrix with dimensions `(1, 3)`. You can see by checking the `shape` of both:

```
>>> numpy.array([1,2,3]).shape
(3,)
>>> numpy.array([[1,2,3]]).shape
(1, 3)
```

`np.array([SwapTargets])` is just the same as the second example above. Its first dimension is of length `1`, and so indexing ends at `0` in the first dimension. You probably want `np.array(SwapTargets)` instead.